# IE 11, Data from server not update

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, internet-explorer-11

I have strange problem with IE11 only. I have form in my app, when I fill all inputs and try save, request to server from IE11 is send properly, then I try get this data and I recive empty collection from resposne (using `axios`). I use polyfill to `promises` and `push`. Where could be a problem ?

In application I use `React`, `Redux`.

Sample code:

```
   getService(id) {
      return this.api.get('/' + id)
          .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data.model.collect) // arr length 0 in other browser data are exist here
            let Collection = [];
            resp.data.model.collect.map((item, idx) => {
                Collection.push(item)
            });
             return Collection;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          })
       }
```

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: @Umesh  
I would like to add that if I refresh page after few seconds data comes properly.

Comment: Apart from being over-complicated (it will simplify to one line), there's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. If something needs fixing, it's probably `api.get`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 but the most strange thing is that request from server comes but is empty, so it's possible that ie 11 cache request or sth,  ? Have no idea, because if server give me repsone it could be not problem from client side, but server?. Of course problem only happen on ie

Comment: If IE11 behaves differently from other browsers, then you have to suspect IE11. But the problem could still be in your client-side code (javaScript). I can't say for certain without sight of `API.get()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 `this.api.get()` I provided by 
`this.api =AxiosProvider(baseUrl)` . My services are classes which extends class named `CoreApi`, where I set thing related with `axios` like interceptors.

Comment: In that case, make absolutely sure the issue is not something caused by settings in IE11 then, if settings don't fix it, raise a problem report (pull request or whatever) with Axios.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Created issue which is resolved :) https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1293#issuecomment-358018442

Comment: @yazpid, Looks like Axnyff steered you in the right direction straight away. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the internet explorer browser uses data cache for load form. It's necessary stop to record cache. for this you need request your api puting in header the pragma parameter

```
header {
  pragma: 'no-cache'
}
```